# how to Insert a value from drop down in the database in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

### generaljournal.blade.php

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    {!!Form::label('Account Type','Account Type',array('class'=>'col-sm-2 control-label'))!!}
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    {!!Form::select('size', array('GL' => 'G/L Account', 'C' => 'Customer','Vendor' => 'Vendor','Bank' => 'Bank Account','Fixed Asset' => 'Fixed Asset','Member' => 'Member'), 'GL')!!}
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

**GeneralController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
         $Generals = new General;
        $Generals->Line_No = $request->Line_No;
        $Generals->Posting_Date = $request->Posting_Date;
        $Generals->Document_No= $request->Document_No;
        $Generals->Account_Type = $request->Account_Type;
        $Generals->save(); 

        return redirect()->action('GeneralController@index');
    }
```

**error is**

> QueryException in Connection.php line 673: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Account_Type' cannot be null (SQL:
>   insert into `general journal` (`Line_No`, `Posting_Date`,
>   `Document_No`, `Account_Type`) values (6000, 20/05/2016, Doc0001, , ))

im getting an error on the account_type which its value should be a selection from the drop down list.Someone please assist i'm new to laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no element in the blade with the name `Account_Type`.
Try changing this

```
{!!Form::select('size', array('GL' => 'G/L Account', 'C' => 'Customer','Vendor' => 'Vendor','Bank' => 'Bank Account','Fixed Asset' => 'Fixed Asset','Member' => 'Member'), 'GL')!!}
```

to this

```
{!!Form::select('Account_Type', array('GL' => 'G/L Account', 'C' => 'Customer','Vendor' => 'Vendor','Bank' => 'Bank Account','Fixed Asset' => 'Fixed Asset','Member' => 'Member'), 'GL')!!}
```

Comment: Happy to help. Please select it as accepted answer.